# I have an issue in sequelize-paginate module , I ant to filter my data on entries basis . but my code is not taking limit attribute in

Tags: sequelize.js

[Image for clue what i basically want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu2DM.png) I want to show my data on table as per entries, but this query is not working properly.

```
 if (req.query.page) {
        var currentpage = page ? parseInt(page, 10) : 1;
    }
    if (req.query.limit) {
        var per_page = limit ? parseInt(limit, 10) : "";
    } 
    
    feedback = await feedbackModel.paginate({
        where: whereStatement,
        per_page,
        Datefilter
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your per_page variable is out of scope. You are initializing it inside of the if statement's code block, and it will return as undefined when you try to use it inside of that paginate method.

Initialize the variable prior to the conditional code blocks like

`let per_page;`

Then when you re-assign the value of the variable inside of the conditional, just do it without a var or let keyword

`per_page = limit ? parseInt(limit, 10) : "";`

It also appears that you'll want to do the same thing with your currentPage variable, which you aren't currently utilizing in the paginate options object.